# Lookup component - cache size

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, lookup

So I just want to know if my line of thinking is correct.

I'm trying to estimate the cache size on a "full cache" look up component (I know I cant set the cache size on the full cache mode, but Its just as a matter of knowledge)

The query it has is

```
Select int_column, big_int_column from myTable
```

as you can imagine I have an integer and a bigint column.
Assuming myTable will have 1 Million rows,  an integer occupies 4 bytes and a bigint occupies 8bites, is it correct to assume that my cache will have 11.4Mb?

each row = 12bytes * 1M rows = 12M bytes

12M bytes/1024 = 11718Kb / 1024 =

Comment: You are close but no cigar, check this out: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/10/18/calculating-the-size-of-your-lookup-cache.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the link I provided in my comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/10/18/calculating-the-size-of-your-lookup-cache.aspx

Your calculation should be as follows:

**Each Row**:

```
12 + 20 + (4*2) B = 40 B
```

**One million rows**:

```
(40 * 1M)/1024/1024 = approx. 38 MB
```